# Get InChI/InChIkey from dbpedia

Tags: rdf, sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I am a new-bee for DBpedia SPARQL. I would like to extract all `inchikey` and `inchi` from DBpedia. I have written following query to do it, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
   PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
   PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

   SELECT * WHERE {
      ?y  a           dbpedia:ChemicalCompound  .
      ?y  rdfs:label  ?Name                     .
      OPTIONAL { ?y dbpedia2:inchi ?inchi }     .
        FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?Name),"en") )
   }
```

[Run Query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+*+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fy+a+dbpedia%3AChemicalCompound.%0D%0A++%3Fy+rdfs%3Alabel+%3FName+.%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B%3Fy+dbpedia2%3Ainchi+%3Finchi%7D+.%0D%0A++FILTER+%28langMatches%28lang%28%3FName%29%2C%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

It gets the `name` but no `inchi`, and `inchi` is a property of [`ChemicalCompound`](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ChemicalCompound) Class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't many chemical compounds with values for this property.  E.g., the following query counts all the triples with that property, and there are just seven:

```sql
select (count(distinct *) as ?n) where {
  ?s dbo:inchi ?o
}
```

[SPARQL results (7)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%28count%28distinct%20*%29%20as%20%3Fn%29%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fs%20dbo%3Ainchi%20%3Fo%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You can see which values have this property:

```sql
select ?s ?o where {
  ?s dbo:inchi ?o
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fs%20%3Fo%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fs%20dbo%3Ainchi%20%3Fo%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

So your query might actually be working as you expect, but you're just missing the few inchi values in the midst of all the compounds that don't have one.  You could order your results to see those compounds with an inchi value first:

```sql
select ?s ?o where {
  ?s a dbo:ChemicalCompound .
  optional { ?s dbo:inchi ?o }
}
order by desc(?o)
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fs%20%3Fo%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fs%20a%20dbo%3AChemicalCompound%20.%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fs%20dbo%3Ainchi%20%3Fo%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20desc%28%3Fo%29&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: for ex if you look [Nitrobenzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrobenzene) ...it has inchi in it... but not displayed in the sparql result :(... so we are still missing something in the query. Thanks anyway Joshua

Comment: @VenkateshMuthukrishnan I see that the Wikipedia article has some of that information, but I don't see where the [DBpedia resource for Nitrobenzene](http://dbpedia.org/page/Nitrobenzene) has that information.  DBpedia is information *extracted* from Wikipedia;  it doesn't have *everything* that Wikipedia has.